# What is the need to encode data with method base64EncodedStringWithOptions?

Tags: ios, objective-c, base64

In one of my iOS projects, due to inconsistency by many developers, I am facing a issue due to incorrect encoding.

Mostly I found that the *NSData* object is encoded using the method *base64EncodedStringWithOptions*. 
The problem is that different parameters are passed for this method, namely:

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, NSDataBase64EncodingOptions) {
// Use zero or one of the following to control the maximum line length after which a line ending is inserted. No line endings are inserted by default.

NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength = 1UL << 0,
NSDataBase64Encoding76CharacterLineLength = 1UL << 1,

NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithCarriageReturn = 1UL << 4,
NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed = 1UL << 5,

} NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_9, 7_0);
```

The issue got solved when I replaced NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength with NSDataBase64Encoding76CharacterLineLength.

Questions is: how to select which kind of NSDataBase64EncodingOptions to be used. 
What is the consequence of using option with no parameter (0). What is the best practice?

Comment: Why don't you try each option and compare the results. You choose the one that matches your need.

Comment: For example, If I `NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength` for the password field and password is more than 64Byte length, the login fails. Other scenarios work otherwise.

Comment: That's why you need to try each option and find out what the requirement is. Sounds like the server expected the encoded password needs the base 64 encoding to use a specific format. You need to find out what that requirement is and match it.